# How to improve UK license plates scanned by OCR

Tags: javascript, react-native, ocr, react-native-vision-camera

I am using OCR to read the UK license plates, but I have a problem with our text detection since 1, 0, 6, 8 and 5 were mistakenly identified as I, O, G, B and S, and vice versa. For example, the number plate BA01 FXO could be detected as BA0I FXO or even 8AOI FX0, but it should be BAOI FXO.
So I want to correct it when OCR scans the license plate number incorrectly with the wrong character and replace the wrong character with the correct one, but I don't know how to do this.

These are the UK license plate rules:

```
Current
It consists of two letters, followed by two numbers that help identify the age of the vehicle, and three letters at the end.

Prefix
It consists of one letter that helps identify the age of the vehicle, followed by one, two or three numbers, and three letters at the end.

Suffix
It consists of three letters, followed by one, two or three numbers, and a single letter at the end that helps identify the age of the vehicle.

Dateless
It can consist of up to four numbers followed by up to three letters, or vice versa. The maximum number of characters is six.

A dateless plate could be more formally described as four alternative rules:

Long Number Prefix: It can consist of up to four numbers followed by up to two letters.
Short Number Prefix: It can consist of up to three numbers followed by up to three letters.
Long Number Suffix: It can consist of up to two letters followed by up to four numbers.
Short Number Suffix: It can consist of up to three letters followed by up to three numbers.
```

Comment: You can add one more layer if you're using a neural network.  Program your rules there.  It's like the human corrections being added to Chat GPT.

Comment: Identifier systems often avoid visually ambiguous characters. Are you sure UK plates really contain both 0 and O?

Comment: Its probably more suited to Software Engineering or Reverse Engineering